# How do I make an embedded Android OS with just one app?

Tags: android, arm, embedded, kiosk-mode

I would like to make my own embedded system built on Android (ARM) just using devices distributed with Android but without their launcher.

**OR**

I want to start Android with my application launched on top and refuse to close it and shutdown Android from my app.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Essentially you're trying to have a custom build of the AOSP where the "Home" is your application. If you look into */packages/apps/Launcher2* you'll find the code for the default Home screen.

If you look at the *AndroidManifest.xml* file in there, you'll see something like this:

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.android.launcher2.Launcher"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Essentialy, this says that this Activity reacts to the

> android.intent.category.HOME *intent*.

When the system finishes booting (the ActivityManager more specifically), sends that intent. So, if you want your app to start instead of the Launcher, just create yourself an app with a similar intent filter and remove the default Launcher2 (take it out of the list in *build/target/product/generic.mk* and put yours instead). Also make sure the relevant .mk file has something like this:

```
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Home
```

So long as your app doesn't provide a way for the user to launch other apps using icons (like the Launcher does), no other app will be started; unless of course something sends an Activity-starting intent from some other path than the one controlled by your app - say by using the "am" command on the target's Android shell.

Comment: is `Home` in `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Home` the app you are replacing Launcher2 with?

Comment: I think `Home` is module name of current launcher used in AOSP. May be old Android builds used Home module for that, nowadays it is Launcher2. So `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Launcher3` should be used, or even `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Launcher2 Launcher3`. Cyanogenmod 12 uses Trebuchet launcher, so for CM build I would use `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Launcher3 Trebuchet`

Answer (score 2):

By the sound of your question you want to create your own custom Android OS build. That is going to be more involved than developing ordinary Android apps and consequently you're going to have to do a lot of reading, especially the Android OS source code.

I recommend you start [here at the Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/).