# Integrate an apk into AOSP's build system and run it on boot

Tags: android, android-source, lineageos

I would like to have an app (LMT from XDA specifically) Bundled in AOSP/LineageOS.
I can do it via adding it in a Android.mk file , so that's not an issue.

My issue is that I want to have this app launch every time I reboot and unlock my phone.
The reason being I disable the navigation bar and use LMT to navigate, but I cannot use it every time I start my phone as LMT does not auto start.

I am on Android 10.

Can anyone help me figure out a way to tell the system to start LMT every boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app that starts first and shows your Home screen, App drawer etc. is called a Launcher.

You can either:

- Have your new app be a Launcher app. You'll need to modify it to add the HOME intent, and also set it as the [default launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22911156/3801327) of the system.
- Or modify your current Launcher app to open your app as soon as it itself starts.